# How to compare two columns in excel to get value from the other column?

Tags: excel, formula

Please check the image for table information.In excel, I would like to compare name2 column to name1 and get the value of ID1 if name2 and name1 are the same.

Which formula should I use for that.? please kindly help out. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$6,MATCH(D2,B$2:B$6,0))
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: It works, Thanks  a lot! :)